# How to find out the characteristics of the following PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $x = x(s), y= y(s), u= u(s), s \in \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic curve of the PDE $$\bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\bigg) - u = 0$$ passing through a given curve $x = 0, y = \tau, u = \tau^2, \tau \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the characteristic are given by

1. $x = 3\tau(e^s-1), y = \dfrac{\tau}{2}(e^{-s}+1), u = \tau^2e^{-2s}$
2. $x = 2\tau(e^s-1), y = {\tau}(2e^{2s}-1), u = \dfrac{\tau^2}{2}(1+e^{-2s})$
3. $x = 2\tau(e^s-1), y = \dfrac{\tau}{2}(e^{s}+1), u = \tau^2e^{2s}$
4. $x = \tau(e^{-s}-1), y = {-2\tau}\bigg(e^{-s}-\dfrac{3}{2}\bigg), u = \tau^2(2e^{-2s}-1)$

As- 3

From (3), we have $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}= 2\tau e^s \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}= \frac{\tau}{2}e^s \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}= 2\tau^2 e^{2s}$$ Now $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial s}}{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}} = \tau e^s \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= \frac{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial s}}{\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}} = 4\tau e^s $$ Now $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 4\tau^2e^{2s}= 4u$$But this donot match with given PDE. Am doing it right or there is any other way of doing it?